# retrieve push remove update nested data inside JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have the following data json :

```
"user" : {
   "id": 456,
   "nickname": "xxx",
   "pf": {
        "id": 123,
        "account": [
            {
                "accountid": 1494235749,
                "status": "New",
                "accountnbr": 12345,
                "cyc": {
                    "cycid": 1494404053,
                    "active": true,
                    "status": "New",
                    "name": "QST192017",
                },

            },
            {
                "accountid": 1494403399,
                "status": "New",
                "accountnbr": 915177,
                "cyc": {
                    "cycleid": 1494406299,
                    "active": true,
                    "status": "Closed",
                    "name": "QSL342014"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
 }
```

I can retrieve the json data in angular2 with this following line :

```
this.user = this.userService.user;
```

also for user.pf and for user.pf.account (all accounts)

Here is my questions :

1. how to get all cyc ?
2. how to add new account / cyc ?
3. how to remove account / cyc ?

Note that each account has only one cyc .
And I m using angular2 .

Thank you.

/K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to get all cyc ?

`this.userService.user.pf.account` keeps all account and also cyc belongs to it. you can just loop through `this.userService.user.pf.account`.

```
// keep cyc in new array
var cycs = [];
this.userService.user.pf.account.forEach(function(account) {
  // each cyc of account can be got here
  console.log(account.cyc);
  cycs.push(account.cyc);
});
```

> how to add new account / cyc ?

```
this.userService.user.pf.account.push(newAccount);   // add new account
this.userService.user.pf.account.cyc = newCyc;       // suppose the current account don't have one cyc, if it has one then will be overwritten
```

> how to remove account / cyc ?

```
this.userService.user.pf.account.splice(index, 1);   // remove account by index
delete this.userService.user.pf.account[index].cyc;         // delete cyc from acccount by index
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer, could you please give an example of how to get all cyc ? (the loop)

Comment: last question : how to put whats in  the loop in array ?  this.cycs = this.userService.user.pf.account.forEach(function(account.cyc){};   Is this correct ?

Comment: OR this.userService.user.pf.account.forEach(function(account) {
         this.cycs.push(account.cyc);   
    });

Comment: @KOul the secons one is good.  I just changed example code which is same to your second one.

Comment: your help is needed for that question  too : 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952847/retrieve-json-list-with-absent-object-and-replace-them-by-null-using-angular2  ;-)