# retrieve JSON list with absent Object and replace them by null using Angular2

Tags: arrays, json, angular

Here is my JSON array :

```
"user" : {
   "id": 456,
   "nickname": "xxx",
   "pf": {
        "id": 123,
        "account": [
            {
                "accountid": 1494235749,
                "status": "New",
                "accountnbr": 12345,
                "cyc": {
                    "cycid": 1494404053,
                    "active": true,
                    "status": "New",
                    "name": "QST192017",
                },

            },
            {
                "accountid": 1494403399,
                "status": "New",
                "accountnbr": 915177,
                "cyc": {
                    "cycleid": 1494406299,
                    "active": true,
                    "status": "Closed",
                    "name": "QSL342014"
                }
            },
            {
                    "accountid": 1494500399,
                    "status": "New",
                    "accountnbr": 90010,
            }
        ]
     },
}
```

And this is what I have in my template :

```
 <tr *ngFor="let account of accounts">
            <td>{{ account.accountnbr }}</td>
            <td>{{ account.cyc.name}}</td>
 </tr>
```

I tried to retrieve a list of all my accounts , and as you can see one of the account has no cyc, and shows an error , any idea how to replace absent JSON object by null in the list  ?

PS : I'm using angular2

Thank you.

/K

Comment: I have updated my question : the purpose  is to display list of all accounts. that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `account.cyc?.name` will solve your problem. when `account` doesn't have `cyc`, your template will just show blank without any error.

see documentation of [safe-navigation-operator(?)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator).

```
<tr *ngFor="let account of accounts">
  <td>{{ account.accountnbr }}</td>
  <td>{{ account.cyc?.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Pegyy: what's that mean this (?)  ?

Comment: @KOul I have add documentation link to answer. one word to say: it will check whether the object exists before retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as using an `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngFor="let acc of account">
    <div *ngIf="!acc.cyc">NO CYC ON THIS ACCOUNT</div>
</div>
```

For this purpose an absent object *is* null/undefined.

You could also map over the object in your component and set it as null:

```
account.map(x =>{
    if(!x.cyc){
        x.cyc = null;
    }
    return x;
});
```

Comment: thank you Tyler for your solution . it's working too.